# Limiting results returned fromquery in django, python

Tags: python, django

I've just started to learn how to do queries in my Django application, and I have a query that gets me the list of new users filtered by the date joined:

```
newUsers = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by("-date_joined")
```

This as I understand it gives me ALL the users, sorted by date joined. How would I best limit it to get me the last N users?

On this, does anyone recommend and reading material to learn more about these types of queries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by("-date_joined")[:10]
```

will give you the last 10 users who joined. See [the Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#id4) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Use list slice operation on constructed queries e.g.

For example, this returns the first 5 objects (LIMIT 5):

```
Entry.objects.all()[:5]
```

This returns the sixth through tenth objects (OFFSET 5 LIMIT 5):

```
Entry.objects.all()[5:10]
```

Read django documentation
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score 2):

```
User.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by("-date_joined")[:10]
```

QuerySets are lazy [ http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/ ]. When you're slicing the list, it doesn't actually fetch all entries, load them up into a list, and then slice them. Instead, it fetches only the last 10 entries.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if u would just divide amount of all user, (for example, 10 per site) you should interest pagination in dJango, very helpful http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#topics-pagination